# Ruby how to ingest UTF_8 transformation

Tags: ruby

all.

I inherited super handy Ruby script to search for string in the file, and now on new file system it give me error `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 errors`.  I did read few post how to apply transformation, but not sure if  I can do this with `File.open(file_name).read()  =~ regex` expression.
Can I somehow ingest that commented line for UDF transformation in my script pasted below ?

```
$VERBOSE = nil                         #  supress warnings
regex = /MM Membership/i  
dirToSearch  =  'C:\TFS\**\*.sql'.gsub "\\","/" 
 
puts '_dirToSearch :        ' + dirToSearch

cc = 0
found = false


    Dir.glob(dirToSearch).each do |file_name|           #     Loop1
        #  string.encode!('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')

         if      File.open(file_name).read()  =~ regex
        then  
           puts  ' 2b  ___Found  ' + file_name +  ' for [' + regex.source + ']'
         end    
end                                                                                                         #______END  Loop 1
```

Comment: Is this exactly how you inherited the script? I wouldn't trust anything I inherited with indentation this bizarre. If the author couldn't even *attempt* to indent their code normally, what else don't they know how to do?

Comment: Thanks Silvio for comment, but there is no any valid point in it. This is perfectly working piece. I pasted below just core part

Comment: "Perfect" is a huge stretch here. This code is a wreck. It's worth cleaning up so we can at least understand what it's doing.

Comment: PSA: The `then` here is really unusual to see. That's something most Ruby programmers never use, it's a relic from the Ruby 1.x days.

Comment: It  `puts`  all files  having  regex in it. Let's imagine that I'm new person for programming and came from country where we have electricity for 2 hrs /day.

Comment: This is likely older code from when Ruby did not understand UTF-8, so you'll need to check the encoding of your input files and set the argument to `open` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks tadman. Can you suggest edit to my code?   `ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) [x64-mingw-ucrt]`  I'm suing free version

Comment: Up until Ruby 1.8 there was no UTF-8 support, it was just bytes. Ruby 1.9 changed that and introduced problems like this. Check your file encoding, and `open(file, encoding: '...')` with the correct encoding type. Maybe it's `"ISO-8859-1"`.

Comment: You can try reading in with `encoding: 'BINARY'` to see what you're dealing with. If it looks like things are weirdly spaced out with zero bytes then it's likely UTF-16 at the source. `p File.open(...).read.inspect()` for more detail.

Comment: Thanks Tadman,   ISO-8859-1  solved all my problems !

Answer (score 0):

solution from tadman worked "ISO-8859-1"